# formula to figure regular wages of 40 hours plus overtime wages to equal a specific number.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have employees who work 60 hours per week and a new law says I have to pay them overtime after 40 hours.

In order for the employees to keep their hours instead of me hiring more employees they are willing to work for lower wages so that the total with overtime equals their current weekly paycheck.

Say, Tom works 60 hours per week at \$10.00 per hour and therefore makes \$600 per week. What would his regular hourly rate be reduced to in order to still equal \$600 per week including 20 hours of overtime (time and 1/2). I need the formula.

Comment: Suppose that they pay-rate is $x$ dollars per hour normally, and therefore the payrate is $1.5x$ dollars per hour for overtime.  If he works for $40$ hours at the normal rate and an additional $20$ hours at the overtime rate, how much money does he make in terms of $x$?  How much money do we want him to make?

Answer (score 1):

Computing overtime can be described as a relation of two piecewise functions. Where $n$ is the number of hours and $k$ is a multiplicative factor of overtime.

$ F(n, k) = P(n,k) + R(n) $

$ P(n,k) = \begin{cases} 0 & n \leq 40 \\
k(n-40) & n > 40
\end{cases}
$

$ R(n) = \begin{cases} n & n \leq 40 \\
40 & n > 40
\end{cases}
$

$ F(n,k) = \begin{cases} 0 & n \leq 40 \\
k(n-40) & n > 40
\end{cases} + \begin{cases} n & n \leq 40 \\
40 & n > 40
\end{cases}
$

This can be further reduced to

$ F(n,k)= \begin{cases} n & n \leq 40 \\
kn-40k+40 & n > 40
\end{cases}
$

The sum value of the work is then described by the function $ T(v, n, k) = v \cdot F(n,k) $

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** You can set up the following equation and solve

$60(r) = 40(x)+20(1.5x)$

where r is the current hourly rate ($10) and x is the new hourly rate.

Comment: Thanks dardeshna, this works great. This keeps Tom (and others) from only working for us 40 hours and then having to find a part time job to make ends meet.

Answer (score 0):

Morally, I figure I should not give this to you.

h = hours worked per week.

w_old = old wages.

Weekly pay = h*w_old

Under new law:

h = hours worked per week.  Stays the same.

w_new = new wages.

Weekly pay = 40*w_new + (h - 40)*(1 1/2)*w_new

So

h*w_old = 40*w_new + (h - 40)*(1 1/2)*w_new

and we solve for w_new

h*w_old = 40*w_new + (h - 40)*(1 1/2)*w_new

h*w_old = 40*w_new + (h - 40)*(3/2)*w_new

h*w_old = 40*w_new + (3/2)h*w_new - 60*w_new

h*w_old = w_new(40 -60 +(3/2)h) = w_new((3/2)h - 60)

$\frac{h*w_{ol}d}{(3/2)h - 60} = w_{new}$

$ w_{new}=\frac{h*w_{old}}{(3/2)h - 60}$

I hope Tom quits on you.